# AWS S3 file access with the correct parameter value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to give access to the object only if the value of the sign parameter in the request is equal to the value of the sign tag of the object. At the same time, the sign tag for each object is different and is set at loading (random UUID).

If there are options for implementing this not using tags, then I would like to know about them

I tried to set up Bucket policy (maybe it will make it clear what I want):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::(MyBucket)/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/sign": "${aws:RequestTag/sign}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the policy? Any errors?

Comment: Also how do you make the requests for the object with that tags? Using AWS CLI? Can you share it?

Comment: @Marcin, only AccessDenied. I use https://(MyBucket).s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/j5k5aoSn1ZI.jpg?sign=key

Comment: @MLedIum Is the problem you are trying to solve that you want to restrict access based on a specific URL? Are you happy if you need to refresh the URL one a week?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes

Comment: @MLedIum Use [S3 presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) with an expiry of 1 week - is that an option? If so, I can write some demo code using the CLI for you in an answer

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary but will it work if I need to generate about 1,000,000 links per day and another 1,000,000 for each previous one and a retention period of 7 days. At the same time, getting a link to the same file or generating a new one without deleting the old one should work.

Comment: Yes it will, if you can handle the generation, there are no limits on the API - only file size (5GB)